# Starting jmeter gui as result tree viewer

Tags: jmeter

I run functional tests written in jmeter via jenkins in non gui mode. I would like to create a script to view tree results in gui mode that starts with the sample results already loaded. Is there a mode to force the gui's view result tree browse+open function on startup? Like clicking on a excel file opens excel with the file loaded.

I'm trying like:
In viewResult.jmx i have a single View Result Tree element and at Filename field is ${__P(resultTreeFile)}

showresult.sh:

```
jmeter -t path/to/viewResults.jmx --jmeterproperty resultTreeFile=path/to/treeResult.xml
```

I didn't find any relevant property in jmeter.properties . Is it possible somehow? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know JMeter does not load the jtl file automatically. You need to browse open the file manually to view the existing results.

**Approach 1:**

I also do some functional testing using JMeter. I create my own simple HTML file. 
To come up with your own html file, you can use `JSR223 Listener`. This [example](https://hellotestworld.com/2013/05/02/write-a-file-from-a-jmeter-script/) shows simple file creation to give you an idea.

**Approach 2:**

You can convert jtl (which is in xml format) to HTML using some xsl files. Check this: http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part1/

You can use Ant targets / jenkins post build actions to convert this.